# How to set a String after Command?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, esp32

```
#define RXD 16
#define TXD 17
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
//#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include <Arduino.h>

//PROTOCOL SYNTAX
const String PREFIX_REQUEST = "#"; //Symbol(s) beginning a query
const String PREFIX_ANSWER = "~@"; //Symbol(s) beginning an answer
const String APPENDIX_QUESTION = "?"; //Symbol(s) following a query
const String APPENDIX_ANSWER = ""; //Symbol(s) following a query
const String READY_MESSAGE = "READY"; //Message sent after boot
const String ERROR_MESSAGE = "unknown command"; //Message sent for unknown query
const int WAIT_TIME = 120;  //time between answers sent //multiples of 60 work best

//SYSTEM QUERYS
const String COMMAND_TEMPERATURE = "TEMPERATURE";
const String COMMAND_VERSION = "VERSION";

//SYSTEM PARAMETERS
const String VERSION = "2.0";

//going to be changed
//PARAMETER ROOMNAME
const String roomname_short = "Test"; //Roomname alias //maximum 8 characters
const String roomname = "Test"; //Roomname full for display on UI

//QUERYS
//uppercase characters and hyphens
//no spaces
//minimum 3 characters
//phrase "INTERNAL"
//Commands using in Hercules
const String COMMAND_ROOMCONFIG = "ROOMCONFIG";
const String COMMAND_ROOMNAME = "ROOMNAME";
const String COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT = "ROOMNAME-SHORT";

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

uint8_t temprature_sens_read();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

uint8_t temprature_sens_read();

void setup() {
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD, TXD);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Serial2.write("A");
  Serial2.println((READY_MESSAGE));
  Serial.println(READY_MESSAGE);
}

void loop() {
  char c;
  String readString;
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    c = Serial2.read();
    readString += c;
  }
  if (readString.length() >= 10) {
    if (readString.substring(1, 9) == "INTERNAL") {
      readString = "";
    }
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(readString);
    readString.trim();
    if (topicMatching(readString, COMMAND_VERSION)) {
      sendAnswer(COMMAND_VERSION + " " + VERSION);
    } else if (topicMatching(readString, COMMAND_TEMPERATURE)) {
      sendAnswer(COMMAND_TEMPERATURE + " " + ((temprature_sens_read() - 32) / 1.8) + " C");
    } else if (topicMatching(readString, COMMAND_ROOMCONFIG)) {
      roomconfig();
    } else if (topicMatching(readString, COMMAND_ROOMNAME)) {
      sendAnswer(COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT + " " + roomname);
    } else if (topicMatching(readString, COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT)) {
      sendAnswer(COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT + " " + roomname_short);
    }
    else {
      sendAnswer(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    readString = "";
  }
}

bool topicMatching(String question, String command) {
  return question == PREFIX_REQUEST + command + APPENDIX_QUESTION;
}

void sendAnswer(String message) {
  Serial2.println(PREFIX_ANSWER + message);
  delay(WAIT_TIME);
}

void roomconfig() {
  sendAnswer(COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT + " " + roomname);
  sendAnswer(COMMAND_ROOMNAME_SHORT + " " + roomname_short);
}
```

So first that´s my Code and I have declared some variables. I use this code in Arduino IDE to save this on it. It keeps some Information like Temperature and Roomnames. The second program which I use is Hercules it´s a Terminal TCP program where I can send Commands.
For Example if I upload this code from arduino to my ESP32 it´s ready after then I switch to Hercules and
type the following ##ROOMNAME  this Command is setting my Roomname and if I hit ##ROOMNAME?  it gives me the name back.

So what I want to do is to set the Name directly on Hercules. Is that possible so my Roomname is not set in Code rather in Hercules by myself.
Something like ##ROOMNAME test

Comment: Just remove `const` from `roomname` then you can assign to the variable?

Comment: but how can I change the String in Hercules ?

Comment: I don't know Hercules but what's the problem with sending `##ROOMNAME test`?

Comment: It says #ROOMNAME test~@unknown command

Comment: Isn't that an error from your own code not from Hercules?

Comment: Yes it is. I want to modify it but I don´t know how to put an Input which will be the new Roomname for example ...